# Unexpected Top-Level Exception in Cordova

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have a Cordova application which has the [Facebook](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) and [PushNotification](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) plugins installed.

When I try to build my application I get the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotat
ion/AnimRes;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:45
4)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:dexDebug FAILED
```

This indicates there's a jar clash in application. Facebook plugin uses `android-support-v4` and PushPlugin uses `android-support-v13`.

I have `android-support-v4.jar`, `bolts-android-1.1.2.jar` and `BUCK` as libs in facebook plugin and `gcm.jar` in Push Plugin.

How can I avoid this jar clash?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: This solved my problem - https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1095

Comment: And this solves mine - https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/992